# Set field required if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to make required a field when button will radio button will be checked.

My jQuery (or JavaScript) are:

```
$('input#availability_to_work-1').change(function () {
if(this.checked) {
    $('input#availability_date_to_work').prop('required', true);
} else {
    $('input#availability_date_to_work').prop('required', false);
}
```

and

```
        $("input[name='availability_to_work']").click(function () {
        if ($("input#availability_to_work-1").is(":checked")) {
            $(".wpjb-element-input-text.wpjb-element-name-availability_date_to_work").show();
        } else {
            $(".wpjb-element-input-text.wpjb-element-name-availability_date_to_work").hide();
        }
    });
```

My CSS:

```
.wpjb-element-input-text.wpjb-element-name-availability_date_to_work{display:none}
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="'od zaraz'" name="availability_to_work" id="availability_to_work-0">
```

```
<div class="wpjb-element-input-text wpjb-element-name-availability_date_to_work" style="display: block;">

            <label class="wpjb-label">
                Data rozpoczęcia pracy                                    </label>

            <div class="wpjb-field">
                <input id="availability_date_to_work" name="availability_date_to_work" type="text" required="">                                                        </div>

        </div>
```

All works good till moment if someone will check button with 'value="'od daty'"' and then check "od zaraz".

Then someone gets error in panel developer when tries to sumbit a form:

```
An invalid form control with name='availability_date_to_work' is not focusable.
```

Could someone help me to fix it?
With checkbox it's work good. Only with radio buttons it doesn't work fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a plunker or JFiddle to show running code, so others can easily understand your problem. Right now, it's too confusing

Comment: It's giving you that error because when something is `display: hidden`, (or in your case inside of a `display: hidden` div) it is not possible for the code to focus on it to make it required. Probably your code to make it required is running *before* the show... you should try to call it after it has been shown.